# How do I compare ASM instruction speeds?

Tags: performance, assembly, latency, instructions

I know that `xorq %rax,%rax` is faster than `movq $0,%rax` because my compiler has told me. However, if I didn't know the answer, what should I do to compare *xorq* and *movq* performances?

What I have tried is this:

```
int main(void)
{
  long a;
  long i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 10000000000l; i++) {
    a = 10;
    __asm__(
#if 0
            "movq $0, %%rax"
#else
            "xorq %%rax, %%rax"
#endif
            : "=a" (a) : "a" (a))
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However when I time the program (once with `#if 0`, once with `#if 1`), I keep getting very similar results (5.876±0.001 seconds). FYI, I have set the scaling governor to the lowest frequency and I have checked the *user* line returned by `time(1)`.

I've also tried with `addq %rax,%rax` vs `imulq $2,%rax`, again with no luck.

I know that modern processors are pretty smart at optimizing code execution, and I guess this is why I'm not getting helpful results. So I'm here to ask: how should I proceed? Am I on the right path?

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: aah, you are right. I have changed the loop and have used 16 _movq/xorq_ per interation instead of just one. Now I'm starting to see some differences. See http://pastebin.com/QfWjAGvj

Comment: @MikeDunlavey: with _addq_ vs _imulq_, the difference is almost 10 seconds. If you turn your comment into an answer, I will accept it as soon as possible.

Comment: There are other advantages - you can zero the 64-bit register using `xorl %eax, %eax` - though you can do this with `movl` too, it's still fewer bytes. The `xor R,R` pattern is also a dependency breaker, and on newer architectures, it doesn't require an execution unit (zero latency).

Comment: Instead of using system time, use the assembly instruction rdtsc which  read the cpu's 64 bit cycle counter into edx:eax, or for windows use queryperformancecounter or for *nix, use clock_gettime (with parameter CLOCK_MONOTONIC). Unfold the loop to 100 or so instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to unroll the guts of the loop a lot of times, like 10 or 100. Otherwise mainly you're measuring the loop overhead. Also I would suggest `for (i = 1000...; --i>=0;)` which might compile into fewer instructions.